# Access XAMPP mysql from powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, xampp

I try to access the XAMPP mysql on my local WINDOWS10 from powershell.
My powershell script works on the mysql db on an external hosting:
(Connection names hidden)

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "*****" -AsPlainText -Force
$user = "*****"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' -ArgumentList $user, $pass
$server = "*****"
Connect-MySqlServer -Credential $cred -ComputerName $server -Database "*****" -Verbose -Debug
```

User, password, database are correct
I have a 1-to-1 copy of webpage and mysql on XAMPP with same tables and users which works fine.
I set
`bind-address="0.0.0.0"`
and
`#skip-networking`
is commented out

Which server name do I use for the XAMPP connection? I tried "localhost" and the local IP
Error message:

```
Connect-MySqlServer : Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Open" mit 0 Argument(en):  "SSL Connection error."
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:7
+ $C2 = Connect-MySqlServer -Credential $cred -ComputerName "127.0.0.1" ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Connect-MySqlServer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this script working for me after installing the [MySQL Connector NET 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/):

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$SQLServer = "localhost"
$SQLDBName = "****"
$uid       = "****"
$pwd       = "****"


$Command             = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$conn                = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=$SQLServer;user id=$uid;password=$pwd;database=$SQLDBName;SslMode=None")
$Command.CommandText = "Your SQL query"
$Command.Connection  = $conn

$Command.Connection.Open()
[int]$i = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Command.Connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the XAMPP shell on your local machine instead.
[image: XAMPP control panel screenshot]

And write the following command (assuming you have not customized default XAMPP settings)

```sh
mysql -u root
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion , works for database operation - but I have more complex powershell procedure wher e like to use the result of the queries.